# Hide first yaxis label

Tags: jqplot

I need to hide the label -200 in yaxis, is there any way to hide the first yaxis label?
So the yaxis label result will be [empty] ,0, 200, 400, 600, 800

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did is return an empty string for negative value.

```
tickOptions: {
                formatter: function (format, value) {
                    if (value < 0) {
                        return ' ';
                    }
                    else {
                        return value
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let say your chart is included in a div with "chart1" as id, you can hide the first yaxis label using :

```
$("div#chart1 div.jqplot-yaxis div.jqplot-yaxis-tick:nth-child(1)").css('display','none');
```

Where `div#chart1` represents your chart, `div.jqplot-yaxis` your yaxis ticks container and `jqplot-yaxis-tick:nth-child(x)` the x-th ticks in this container (it goes from 1 to number of ticks - where 1 represents the ticks at the bottom of your chart)